# How to Customize CCNet UI

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

How to customize my CCNet UI ?.At present I am reading my msbuild scripts  through ccnet.config. revision no and all target is already set in scripts.but i dont want to specify revision no in scripts, it should be mentioned in ccnet UI.so when user enter any revision no in UI ,based on Reviosion it should create the build.

how to get resolved this issue using ccnet UI.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Your question title makes it sound like you want to customize the CCNET User Interface (i.e. the web dashboard), but your question sounds like you want to customize the output of your MSBuild command. Please give some more details.

Comment: actullay,my revision no is set in msbuild scripts.i mean its hard code.my ccnet config reading the scripts and generating the build.every time i am going and change revision no in scripts file.but i want its should be dynamic.user enter any revision it will create build based on entered revision no.pls suggest how to achieve it

Comment: One option is to "tag" your code with your REPOSITORY number/tag.  Like, with SVN, it would be the revision number.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to prompt the user for a revision number on which to build.  Use CCNet's [dynamic parameters](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Dynamic_Parameters).

Comment: i didnt catch it.pls could you explain over on it

Comment: <tasks> <msbuild> <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable> <workingDirectory>E:\ww</workingDirectory> <buildArgs>demo.xml</buildArgs> <targets>Release</targets> </msbuild> </tasks>it is my ccnet.config and its reading demo.xml.in demo xml i have written msbuild target and revision no is also defined in demo.xml

Comment: I've never use dynamic parameters, so can't give any more help. You'll have to rely on the docs. Sorry.